# Hosts file redirect to local computer directory

Tags: windows, apache, dns, hosts, local-network

I have a local Apache server running on my desktop which allows me to run a local site which I want to access from my laptop.

I'm able to access the computer in my hosts file using '192.168.0.5    liam.pc' but I can't figure out how to enter a directory. I've tried '192.168.0.5/Hudex/public    hudex.dev' but it doesn't seem to work.

How can I accomplish the effect I want?

HOSTS file:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
127.0.0.1    zheil.dev
192.168.0.5    liam.pc
```

Comment: The hosts file won't do this for you; you'll need to configure your local web server accordingly. (In Apache, you'll need multiple `VirtualHost`s)